# Are questions about software packages on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it on topic to ask questions of the form "What program does allow me to do X"? Or more generally, is it on topic to ask questions about *recommendations* for certain programs? I fear that these questions may be suited better for superuser.com...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is on-topic.  We already have many questions like this.

Yes, there is some overlap with SuperUser, which is unfortunate.  But in general here you are asking *nix experts for advice on apps for your *nix system, which seems appropriate.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was not so sure when browsing through some questions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't ask something like "what is the best web browser to use on linux and windows?" you're probably fine.

Comment: Links, for sure!